# splice is not working as expected in for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert the name based on the position to the list.
but the splice is not working properly.

the list expected result should be = [
"x",
"x",
"tester1",
"tester2",
"x",
"x",
"tester1",
"tester2",
"x",
"x",
"x",
"x",
"x",
"x",
"tester1",
"tester2"
]

```js
var list = ['x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x'];
var data = [{name:'tester1',position:'3,5,last'},{name:'tester2',position:'3,5,last'}]

 

for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  var position = data[i].position.split(",");
  var name = data[i].name;
  for (var x=0; x<position.length; x++){
    if(!isNaN(position[x])){
      position[x] -= 1;
      list.splice(position[x], 0, name);
    }else{
      list.splice(list.length, 0, name);
    }
  }
}

console.log('list',list)
```

Comment: Have you tried walking through this using a debugger?

Comment: Can you define why the result you mention is the expected result? The result you're getting from the snippet is the result I expected just from looking at the `list` and `data` variables, and without reading the code at all. Can you articulate what the logic is that you want to use, which means those inputs should provide the result you want?

Comment: yes as per checking it seems that the splice is not working as expected and not inserting based on the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is, that in each iteration you will change the `list` and therefore the positions are not correct anymore.

So a solution for that might be:

```js
var list = ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'];
var data = [
  { name: 'tester1', position: '3,5,last' },
  { name: 'tester2', position: '3,5,last' }
];

const getListWithAdditions = (list, data) => {
  const positionsDict = {};
  const resultList = [];

  // step 1: ----
  // create an object like { <index>: ['<name>', '<name>'], last: ['<name'>, '<name>'] }
  data.forEach(({ position, name }) => {
    position.split(',').forEach(pos => {
      const dictKey = isNaN(pos - 1) ? pos : `${pos - 1}`;
      positionsDict[dictKey] = [...(positionsDict[dictKey] || []), name];
    });
  });

  // step 2: ----
  // create the new list and add the saved names to it.
  list.forEach((listItem, index) => {
    const dictKey = index.toString();
    const addition = [...(positionsDict[dictKey] || []), listItem];
    resultList.push(...addition);
  });

  return positionsDict.last
    ? [...resultList, ...positionsDict.last]
    : resultList;
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(getListWithAdditions(list, data)));
// ["x","x","tester1","tester2","x","x","tester1","tester2","x","x","x","x","x","x","tester1","tester2"]
```

It does not really look like clean code at the moment, but the logic is correct.

Comment: Thanks, will accept this as the answer as the expected result is solved.
Using a spread and the array index seems solve the problem.
I think I'm having issue as I'm looping twice the array and using splice which I'm currently having trouble.

Comment: Thank you! The problem with splice is, that you mutate the list. Meaning, that after the first loop the positions in your data list are different now because the list ist now one item longer then before.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was suspecting too. Thank for the explanation and for the solution, now I have an idea where I will start implementing the logic.